# Laravel API with download Image via url

Tags: mysql, laravel, api

I have an API project using Laravel and these requires me to have a download and save it to public folder and in database.

Flow:

A field will come through the API call, i.e. through the company_logo field. It will come through as a URL: http://a.mktgcdn.com/p/Lr5Sfx0OllncmEPfQGX11ZqUZSmcUhbvc5a-u-FrMCU/1.0000/300x300.jpg. I need to grab the image and save it locally to a unique folder per listing and save it also to database.

I don't have code yet because I don't know what to do here in Laravel.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do that by using [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/use/basics#creating)

You can find how to install [here](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)

```
$path = 'http://a.mktgcdn.com/p/Lr5Sfx0OllncmEPfQGX11ZqUZSmcUhbvc5a-u-FrMCU/1.0000/300x300.jpg';
$filename = basename($path);
Image::make($path)->save(public_path('yourimagefolder/' . $filename));
```

this will save the image. and following code will save it to database

```
$image = new ModelName();
$image->imagename  =$filename;
$image->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help, you need to define $url and $filename variable

```
$data = file_get_contents( $url );
file_put_contents( public_path($filename), $data );
```